# Xenomai RTDM Skins for I2C, SPI

Tags: i2c, real-time

In [another post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1408/is-it-possible-to-run-real-time-software) I read that Xenomai could be used for real-time tasks like control loops.

I'd need to implement a real-time task which also talks to I2C and SPI. In [this mailing list message](http://www.mail-archive.com/xenomai-help@gna.org/msg07998.html) I read that the clean way to implement this in Xenomai would be an (own) RTDM Skin driver implementation for each device.

**Are there any Xenomai RTDM Skins for the RPi already?**

And has someone good/bad experiences running Xenomai on the RPi? I've found [these](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=fr&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&u=http://www.blaess.fr/christophe/2012/08/27/xenomai-sur-raspberry-pi/) [three](http://powet.eu/2012/07/25/raspberry-pi-xenomai/) [tutorials](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=41&t=12368) on how to set up Xenomai on the RPi.

Comment: You should possibly ask the person who answered the question? Sticking with Arduino and the vast open community would have made your life allot easier.

Comment: I'd like to do some web service stuff too, so it would be nice if both this and the real time tasks using I2C and SPI could coexist on one controller.

Comment: You can use Occidentalis (Rasbian) and you can install `node` , `nginx`, `apache` , `lighttpd` for web servers that can provide web services. And Also MySQL. Then Arduino connected via UART / I2C, does the real time stuff in pure C (Arduino IDE has tons of examples and libraries) on an ATiny (~2USD) and dump the data to the Pi. If you need the aTiny to do something you convert your web service requests into data and pipe the commands into a script that pushes data via UART /I2C command the aTiny.

Comment: I figured that possibility from http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1408/is-it-possible-to-run-real-time-software/3590#3590. Nonetheless I'd like to investigate into alternative solutions, I'm still at the research phase.

Comment: LinuxCNC supports the RaspberryPi with Xenomai kernel. Someone was working on or has an RTDM GPIO driver.

Comment: Here is a step by step intro to Xenomai and RPi 1
http://userk.co.uk/real-time-system-with-raspberry-pi/

Here is a message about I2C rtdm driver. See the attachment:
www.xenomai.org/pipermail/xenomai/2014-June/03a1107.html
Any news so far?